# jQuery: My blinking text won't be visible, after ending blinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was working on a text-blinking code, and noticed that this code below will sometimes, depending on the timing, make **the text to remain hidden after stopping the animation**:

```
//Blink settings
var blink = {
    obj: $(".blink"),
    timeout: 15000,
    speed: 1000
};

//Start function
blink.fn = setInterval(function () {
    blink.obj.fadeToggle(blink.speed);
}, blink.speed + 100);
//End blink animation, after 'blink.timeout' millisecons
setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(blink.fn);
    blink = null;
}, blink.timeout);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/mksh4eu3/)

I tried adding `blink.obj.show()`, `blink.obj.css(...)` etc. right after `clearInterval(blink.fn);` but [it did not work](http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/mksh4eu3/2/).

```
...
setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(blink.fn);
    blink.obj.show();
    blink.obj.css("visibility","visible");
...
```

**I want the text to ALWAYS be visible after the blinking stops**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `blink.obj.fadeIn()` after the blinking is done..

If you want to mantain the speed, then `blink.obj.fadeIn(blink.speed)`:

```
...code...code...
//End blink animation, after 'blink.timeout' millisecons
setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(blink.fn);
    //The solution to your problem is in the line below
    blink.obj.fadeIn(blink.speed);
    blink = null;
}, blink.timeout);
...
```

Here is the jsfiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/jormaechea/mksh4eu3/7/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just fine just get rid of the `+100` you added. Try this with removed 100, since it is multiple of 100 and 15000 is less than that amount when it reaches there

```js
//Blink settings
var blink = {
  obj: $(".blink"),
  timeout: 15000,
  speed: 1000
};

//Start function
blink.fn = setInterval(function () {
  blink.obj.fadeToggle(blink.speed);
}, blink.speed+100);
//End blink animation, after 'blink.timeout' millisecons
setTimeout(function () {
  clearInterval(blink.fn);
  blink.obj.fadeIn(blink.speed+1);
  blink = null;
}, blink.timeout);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blink">Flashing Text</div>
```

EDIT 2: So then you have to top the number of the `blink.obj.fadeToggle(blink.speed);` by adding atleast a millisecond more to this on your stop function `blink.obj.fadeIn(blink.speed+1);`

Comment: I want it to work regardless of the `speed` or `timeout` values

Comment: @Omar So then you have to top the number of the `blink.obj.fadeToggle(blink.speed);` by adding atleast a millisecond more to this on your stop function `blink.obj.fadeIn(blink.speed+1);` updated snippet

Comment: For example, if I do what you suggested, and then in the future I (or someone else) change the code to `timeout: 15100, speed: 1000`, I'll have the same problem. Or `timeout: 15000, speed: 1100`, or whatever other int combo, it will/may activate the bug

Comment: No it should be fine with any combinations `timeout: 15100, speed: 1000` Or `timeout: 15000, speed: 1100`